# Managing Test & Production API keys in Javascript with .Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

Hi is there a way of telling Javascript which API key to use depending on the build of the application ?

I'm using stripe and I want to use the test keys for development but use the Live key when I deploy to Production. Ideally I don't want to have to remember to manually change the key each time I deploy.

Is there a Javascript equivalent to Web.Config that can be compiled/generated differently depending on the solution configuration ?

Comment: JavaScript is a programming language not a framework. There is such a way if you implement it yourself.

Comment: a simple way is to just inject it in your html as a meta tag or something and then just read that from your javascript